# Preposition “To” after “and”

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I’m confused:

1. “He expressed his gratitude to the Ministry and to the international organisations”
   Should I use “to” after “and” in this sentence?
2. “He expressed his gratitude to the Government and people of Spain”
   There is no “to” after “and” here.

Which one is correct?

What is the rule of using “of” in similar cases?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct.

It's usual to include a second 'to' when the two people or things mentioned are not closely linked. In the first sentence, the subject thanks a government department, presumably in his own country, and *also* international organisations.

In the second sentence, *the government and people of Spain* means 'the whole nation', not two separate bodies.

Answer (score 0):

> “He expressed his gratitude to the Ministry and to the international organisations”

Here there are two separate sets of expression of gratitude:

= “He expressed his gratitude to the Ministry and *he expressed his gratitude* to the international organisations”

> “He expressed his gratitude to the Ministry and the international organisations”

Here, there is one set of gratitude that is given to both.

“He expressed his gratitude {to the Ministry and the international organisations.}”